# Regexp to strip off only ending numbers or chars after _ at the end of a string

Tags: regex, chars

I'd like to have a regexp in java to only strip off numbers if they are at the end of the string and everything after the underscore.

```
1) massi_xxx -> massi
2) massi_12121 -> massi
3) massi123 -> massi
4) 123massi1 -> 123massi
```

I found that
    (?=[0-9_]).* 
works fine for 1,2,3 use case but not for 4)
Any idea on how to refine it?

Thanks
M.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work for most flavors:

```
(?:_.*|\d*)$
```

We match either `_` followed by anything until the end of the string. Or we match a bunch of digits until the end of string. (The end of string is represented by the anchor `$`)

[Working demo.](http://regexr.com?32tb8)

Some flavors might choke upon the `?:` which is really just an optimization. You can as well leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

`(_.*|\d+)$` will match underscore followed by anything or digits at the end of a string. Does that meet your requirement? (I used http://www.regextester.com/ for testing.)